# What does "0003" under Remarks mean in a Schengen Visa issued by Slovenia?

Tags: schengen-visas, slovenia

I just received a Schengen Visa from Slovenia and it says '0003' under remarks. What does that mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The codes used in the remarks section differ from country to country. 0003 on a Slovenian visa does not mean anything more than that the visa is issued for tourism.